Time-dependent covariates and optimism of results
I have a dataset spanning 2019-2023, and a set of categorical covariates that join by year and zip code. For validation, 2023 is left out, and the covariates for that year are an average of previous years. The model during cross validation based on random split shows tremendous optimism. When evaluated on the test data, are not even close. I have proposed to use estimates for the covariates being used to train the model as well, rather than raw values.
Can anyone please point me to literature on this topic? It is spatial-temporal, but involving estimates on new time periods.
Thank you

What you are doing is forecasting. We have resources here: Resources/books for project on forecasting models.
Basically, don't do random splits in cross validation. If there is strong autocorrelation in your data, and June 2022 is in the training data, and July 2022 is in the test data for a particular cross validation run, then your model will have rather an easy time, since it essentially only forecasts one month out. And then it is asked to forecast a full year out... of course it will perform worse then.
Worse: random splits in time series mean that you are "learning from the future". It's much easier to predict 06/2022 if you have data up to 05/2022 and data from 07/2022 and later... but that of course does not happen in later production.
Therefore, the standard approach in time series forecasting is to respect the time ordering in your split: make training, validation and testing data follow one another. For instance, use the data up to 12/2021 for training, validate on 01-12/2022, select models based on the performance on this holdout sample, finally test on 01-12/2023. Note that the validation sample is as long as your test sample (whose length should of course be informed by the forecast horizon you will be using later in production - or consider a rolling origin evaluation, https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html).
In terms of the covariates, how you deal with them should reflect your later "production" situation. If your covariates are the weather, then you should be using weather forecasts in the validation and test phases, because anything else simulates certainty you will not have in production. If your covariates are marketing activities or prices you set, then you can (probably) use the true values, since these are intervention variables you will be able to set in production, as well. (This depends very much on your situation. Often prices are set to clear inventory, so you don't have quite as much freedom here as you might think or want. Scenario analyses might be useful.)
And if you are in the "I need to forecast my covariates" situation, using the average of previous years may be one useful way of forecasting them - but you might be able to do a better job. Again, it makes sense to think about the workflow you will use "in production": say you have decided on a model, it's December 2024, and you want to forecast for all of 2025... how precisely will you set the covariates for this future year? Whatever process for setting or forecasting the covariates you will be using in December 2024 is a useful starting point for dealing with "future" covariates now, when you are deciding on a forecasting method and workflow.
